# How can I load constant variable from src into craco.config.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, craco

I'm using typescript React for the web app and it is using craco.config.js.
I have color declaration in src/theme.ts and I want to import that constant from theme.ts into craco.config.js so I can use that constant to declare modifyVars.

But when I tried import { colorDict} from './src/theme', it raises that it is not a module
When I also tried const {colorDict} = require('/src/theme.ts'), it raises syntax error that SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (Which shows import statement inside theme.ts is raising an error)

I also tried creating separate file and declare colorDict in there but then it causes an error when I try to load in theme.ts or craco.config.js.
(tried using module.exports or export)

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

`craco.config` can't use ES6 (or typescript), it has to be commonjs (`module.exports`), not ESM (import/export)

So the simple answer is to change your `src/theme.ts` to be `src/theme.js` and use CJS (`module.exports`) and, if you need the types in your project create `src/theme.d.ts` for declaring the types separately.